# MSSQL Query to defer income by dividing over the next 12 months

Tags: sql-server, date, revenue

hope you are staying safe ! . I have a requirement to defer income from our memberships sales over 12 months. my table has 2 columns :

```
1. SaleDate.
2. Revenue
```

I need to split the revenue into 12 months . for example if the membership cost $1200 and is sold on june 17 then each month would get $100 and the date needs to look like this

```
Date           Revenue
June           100
july           100
August         100
September      100
```

and so on until May .

So it's basically a running total of all the revenue we make divided by the next 12 months . and we would do the same thing every month. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: i appreciate the feedback and will make sure that next time i add more details and also explain what ive done . thanks !

Comment: thank you so much for this question. Have been searching for weeks for exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with a `CROSS JOIN`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SaleDate] date,[Revenue] money)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2020-06-17',1200)
 
Select [Date]    =dateadd(month,n,[SaleDate])
      ,[Revenue] =A.Revenue/12
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Join ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11) ) B(n)
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Revenue
2020-06-17  100.00
2020-07-17  100.00
2020-08-17  100.00
2020-09-17  100.00
2020-10-17  100.00
2020-11-17  100.00
2020-12-17  100.00
2021-01-17  100.00
2021-02-17  100.00
2021-03-17  100.00
2021-04-17  100.00
2021-05-17  100.00
```

Comment: Thanks @John that worked great! . I appreciate your work and time spent on this query .

Comment: @LuisA Always happy to help